# copy constructor in c++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
class A1{
public:
    A1(){}
    A1(const A1& rhs){}
    void foo() {std::cout<<"Hello";}
};

class A2: public A1{
public:
    A2(){}
    A2(const A2& rhs){}
    void foo1(A1&rhs){rhs.foo();}
    void foo2(A1 a1){a1.foo();}
};

int main()
{
    A2 a2;
    A1 a1(a2);

    a2.foo1(a1);
    a2.foo2(a1);
}
```

How many times are the A1's copy constructor invoked?
How many times are the A2's copy constructor invoked?

Could anybody can teach me this? thanks!

Comment: For the answer to "how many times?", you can put something like `cout << "in A1's ctor" << endl;` in the constructors and run the code to see for yourself.

Comment: @Martinho - If you were even lazier, you could do `static int i = 0; std::cout << ++i << "th time in A1" << std::endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to talk about code that doesn't reuse variable names everywhere.

The copy constructor for `A1` is called twice, and for `A2` not at all.

```
class A1{
public:
    A1(){}
    A1(const A1& rhs){}
    void foo() {std::cout<<"Hello";}
};

class A2: public A1{
public:
    A2(){}
    A2(const A2& rhs){}
    void foo1(A1& a1byref){a1byref.foo();}
    void foo2(A1 a1byval){a1byval.foo();}
};

int main()
{
    A2 a2;
    A1 a1(a2); // calls A1 copy constructor

    a2.foo1(a1);
    a2.foo2(a1); // calls A1 copy constructor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your code slightly for more explicit output, I have:

```
#include <iostream>

class A1{
public:
    A1(){}
    A1(const A1& rhs)
        { std::cout << "A1::copy_ctor\n"; }
    void foo()
        { std::cout << "A1::foo\n"; }
};

class A2: public A1{
public:
    A2(){}
    A2(const A2& rhs){}
    void foo1(A1&rhs)
        {
        std::cout << "A2::foo1\n";
        rhs.foo();
        }
    void foo2(A1 a1)
        {
        std::cout << "A2::foo2\n";
        a1.foo();
        }
};

int main()
{
    A2 a2;
    A1 a1(a2);

    a2.foo1(a1);
    a2.foo2(a1);
}
```

Which using Xcode 3.2.5 yields:

```
A1::copy_ctor
A2::foo1
A1::foo
A1::copy_ctor
A2::foo2
A1::foo
```